# MAX() SQL Server multiple rows. How fix to return only 1 row per month year?

Tags: sql-server, max

I needed help with using the function MAX() properly as I seem to be getting more than one row when I have clearly stated that I want the MAX(Monthid), which should return the last monthyear row for the customer.

What I need is the last monthyear row for either customer_segment or agreement. When I finally put the customer_segment and agreement columns to the original, I get upto 6 different monthyear rows wiht different customer_segment names when I only want 1 row.

How do fix this?

```
--Finding customer segment
    SELECT  
             a.[cust_no]
          ,Customer_Segment
            ,max(monthid) AS monthyear
            INTO #Segment
      FROM Original_table a
      INNER JOIN Customer_Segment ku
        on ku.Cust_no=a.cust_no

    GROUP BY a.cust_no,Customer_Segment
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Finding agreement(yes/no)


  SELECT DISTINCT 
  a.cust_no,
  Agreement,
  max(monthid) as Monthyear
  into #Agreement
  FROM Original_table a
  INNER JOIN Cust_Details zx
    ON zx.cust_no=a.cust_no 

    GROUP BY a.cust_no,
        zx.Agreement
    ------------------------------------------------
-- Attaching columns to original file on cust_no
select DISTINCT 

A.cust_no,
B.Customer_Segment,
d.Agreement

from Original_table A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #Segment ) b
    on b.cust_no=A.cust_no

LEFT JOIN( SELECT  distinct *  FROM #Agreement ) d
    ON d.cust_no=a.cust_no
```

Comment: I guess Group By is the problem. Please share an sql fiddle

Comment: What is a SQL FIDDLE?

Comment: Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing some info on the joins?

```
(...)
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #Segment ) b
    on b.cust_no=A.cust_no and
b.Customer_Segment = A.Customer_Segment

LEFT JOIN( SELECT  distinct *  FROM #Agreement ) d
    ON d.cust_no=a.cust_no and
d.Agreement = A.Agreement
```

Comment: No, I am not missing any additional joins. The only common variable between in them is "cust_no. I tried this on  the customer_segment table only and wrote: SELECT cust_no,customer_segment,MAX(monthid) as monthyear)  from cccxc GROUP BY cust_no,customer_segment  I get doubles. I even made sure to convert the max variable to int. It does not work

Comment: but if you have more than 1 agreement for a costumer, grouping by costumer and agreement you will get more than 1 row offcourse. can you provide some sample data? If possible in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: How do I retrieve the last record of a customer? I get several rows of monthyear and customer_segment. The Agreement is either yes or No. I am trying to only retrieve the last available record for a customer. How would I write that?

Comment: have you looked into using ROW_ NUMBER()?

Comment: you can do it like @TabAlleman suggested, ROW_NUMBER() AS (PARTITION BY cust_no ORDER BY monthid desc) myOrder and then filter for myOrder = 1 on the join maybe.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select 
  A.cust_no, b.monthyear,
  e.Customer_Segment,
  d.Agreement    
from Original_table A
JOIN (SELECT a.[cust_no] cust_no ,max(monthid) AS monthyear
      FROM Original_table a) b on b.cust_no=A.cust_no
OUTER APPLY 
( SELECT TOP 1 Agreement FROM Cust_Details d
  WHERE d.cust_no=a.cust_no
  ORDER BY Agreement
) d
OUTER APPLY 
( SELECT TOP 1 Customer_Segment FROM Customer_Segment e 
  WHERE e.cust_no=a.cust_no
  ORDER BY Customer_Segment
) e
```